# How to convert 3 channels as a RGB image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, rgb

I split a RGB image into R,G,B channels. After processing on these channels, I need to concatenated them. I searched this but find any thing, so I do it with for loops. But it doesn't work well.

```
B,G,R = cv2.split(image)

#some process is here

#result after concatenate
res = np.zeros((image.shape))

for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image.shape[1]):
        res[i,j,0]= B1[i,j]

for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image.shape[1]):
        res[i,j,1]= G1[i,j]

for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image.shape[1]):
        res[i,j,2]= R1[i,j]
```

but it returns a binary image instead.

Comment: Did you try cv2.merge?

Comment: OP found `split`... docs directly point to `merge` in the "see also" section: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga0547c7fed86152d7e9d0096029c8518a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont write loops, use [merge()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga7d7b4d6c6ee504b30a20b1680029c7b4) instead.

as simple as:

```
bgr = cv2.merge([B,G,R])
```

Comment: Thankyou . this solution works but cv2.imshow() doesn't show any thing but binary image in this case :((

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
res = np.zeros_like(image)
```

you will be assured of getting the same `dtype` and your code will likely work.

Also, try to avoid using `for` loops, they are slow and error-prone. Either use `cv2.merge()` as suggested by @berak, or use Numpy:

```
bgr = np.dstack((B,G,R))
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't work in my code. I don't know why.